# MySQL - Concurrent SELECTS - one client waits for another?

Tags: mysql, select, myisam, concurrency

I have the following scenario:

I have a database with a particular MyISAM table of about 4 million rows. I use stored procedures (MySQL Version 5.1) and one in particular to search through these rows on various criteria. This table has several indexes on it, and the queries through this stored procedure are normally very fast ( <1s). Basically I use a prepared statement and create and execute some dynamic SQL in this search sp. After executing the prepared statement, I perform "DEALLOCATE PREPARED stmt;"

Most of the queries run in under a second (I use LIMIT to get just 15 rows at any time). However, there are some rare queries which take longer to run (say 2-3s). I have optimized the searched table as far as I can.

I have developed a web application and I can run and see the results of the fast queries in under a second on my development machine.

However, if I open two browser instances and do a simultaneous search (against the development machine), one with the longer running query, and the other with the faster query, the results are returned at the same time, i.e. it seems as if the fast query waits for the slower query to finish before returning the results. i.e. both queries will take 2-3 seconds...

Is there a reason for this? Because I thought that MyISAM handles SELECTS irrespective of one another and currently this is not the behaviour I am experiencing...

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just due to you doing it from the same machine, if the searches were coming from two different machines they would go at the same time. Would you really like one person to be able to bog down your MySQL server just by opening a bunch of browser windows and hitting refresh?

Comment: Could be the reason! I have not yet tried it from different machines, but I presume you're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is right. Each select query on a MyISAM table locks the entire table until it is finished. Their excuse is that this achieves "a very high read throughput". Switching to innoDB will allow concurrent reads.

Comment: I'd like to see a reference for that claim. What I can make out of the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) concurrent selects **do not** block eachother (they acquire a read lock).